# How can I set up a redundant MongoDB template?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a MongoDB with two redundant MongoS router hosts.  When using org.springframework.data.mongo to create a MongoTemplate and MongoClient, I can only add a single host.  In the event that the host in use falls over, there is no failover to the alternate router host.

I initially referenced https://dzone.com/articles/multiple-mongodb-connectors-with-spring-boot , but the use case there is for two entirely different repositories, where as my case is a single database with dual routers.

In the code below, we would like to add a redundant second host in case the first host fails during runtime.

```
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Value("${mongo.database}")
    private String databaseName;

    @Value("${mongo.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${mongo.readFromSecondary}")
    private String readFromSecondary;

    @Value("${mongo.port}")
    private int port;

    @VaultKey("vault.mongo_username")
    private String username;

    @VaultKey("vault.mongo_password")
    private String password;

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return databaseName;
    }

    @Override
    @Primary
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        final ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress(host, port);
        final MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(username, 
            getDatabaseName(), password.toCharArray());
        return new MongoClient(serverAddress, credential,
            MongoClientOptions.builder().build());
    }

    @Override
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "mongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        final MongoTemplate template = super.mongoTemplate();
        if (this.readFromSecondary != null && Boolean.valueOf(this.readFromSecondary)) {
            template.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondary());
        }

        return template;
    }
}
```

Currently at startup a connection to the host in the config file will be loaded with out error, we would like to rotate in a backup host.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by two ways:

**1. Multiple Mongo Client or multiple Server Address(hosts):**

A MongoDB client with internal connection pooling. For most applications, you should have one MongoClient instance for the entire JVM.

The following are equivalent, and all connect to the local database running on the default port:

```
MongoClient mongoClient1 = new MongoClient();
MongoClient mongoClient1 = new MongoClient("localhost");
MongoClient mongoClient2 = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
MongoClient mongoClient4 = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost"));
MongoClient mongoClient5 = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost"), 
    new MongoClientOptions.Builder().build());
```

You can connect to a replica set using the Java driver by passing a ServerAddress list to the MongoClient constructor. For example:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(
   new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017),
   new ServerAddress("localhost", 27018),
   new ServerAddress("localhost", 27019)));
```

You can connect to a sharded cluster using the same constructor. MongoClient will auto-detect whether the servers are a list of replica set members or a list of mongos servers.

By default, all read and write operations will be made on the primary, but it's possible to read from secondaries by changing the read preference:

```
mongoClient.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred());
```

By default, all write operations will wait for acknowledgment by the server, as the default write concern is `WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED`

**2. Using Multiple Mongo Connectors and Multiple Mongo Templates:**

First of all create the following `@ConfigurationProperties` class.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mongodb")
public class MultipleMongoProperties {
    private MongoProperties primary = new MongoProperties();
    private MongoProperties secondary = new MongoProperties();
}
```

And then add the following properties in the `application.yml`

```
mongodb:
  primary:
    host: localhost
    port: 27017
    database: second
  secondary:
    host: localhost
    port: 27017
    database: second
```

Now it’s necessary to create the MongoTemplates to bind the given configuration in the previous step.

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MultipleMongoProperties.class)
public class MultipleMongoConfig {

    private final MultipleMongoProperties mongoProperties;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "primaryMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate primaryMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(primaryFactory(this.mongoProperties.getPrimary()));
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate secondaryMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(secondaryFactory(this.mongoProperties.getSecondary()));
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MongoDbFactory primaryFactory(final MongoProperties mongo) throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(mongo.getHost(), mongo.getPort()),
                mongo.getDatabase());
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory secondaryFactory(final MongoProperties mongo) throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(mongo.getHost(), mongo.getPort()),
                mongo.getDatabase());
    }

}
```

With the configuration above you’ll be able to have two different MongoTemplates based in the custom configuration properties that we provided previously in this guide.

In the previous step we created two MongoTemplates, `primaryMongoTemplate` and `secondaryMongoTemplate`

More details: https://blog.marcosbarbero.com/multiple-mongodb-connectors-in-spring-boot/